# Keep always getting "maximum recursive updates exceeded" in my component, with no recursive call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recursion, vuejs3, vue-options-api

I'm bulding a shopping list generator app with Vue3, I do call some functions on life cycle hooks such as updated() or mounted(), but not as much as I think I would need to get the "maximum recursive updates exceeded" message on console.

```
<script>
import AddItemModal from "@/components/AddItemModal.vue";
import NewItemButton from "../components/NewItemButton.vue";
import ShoppingItem from "../components/ShoppingItem.vue";
import GenerateListButton from "@/components/GenerateListButton.vue";
import ListComponent from "@/components/ListComponent.vue";

export default { 
    name: "DashboardView",
    components: {
        ShoppingItem,
        NewItemButton,
        AddItemModal,
        GenerateListButton,
        ListComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [],
            itemsToGen: null,
            showGenerateListBtn: false,
            showList: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleShowList() {
            this.showList === false ? this.showList = true : null
        },
        generateList() {
            this.items.length > 0 ? this.toggleShowList() : null

            this.itemsToGen = this.items.filter(item => item.isSelected)
            this.$store.dispatch("setList", this.itemsToGen)
        },
        getChangesFromRender(item, itemIndex) {
            this.items[itemIndex] = item
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getItems() {
            return this.$store.getters.getItems
        },
        getList() {
            return this.$store.getters.getGeneratedList
        },
        checkGenerateListBtn() {
            return this.items.length > 0 ? true : false
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch("getItemsFromLocal")
        this.$store.dispatch("getListFromLocal")
        this.items = this.getItems
        this.itemsToGen = this.getList
        this.showGenerateListBtn = this.checkGenerateListBtn

        this.itemsToGen ? this.toggleShowList() : null
    },
    updated() {
        this.showGenerateListBtn = this.checkGenerateListBtn
        this.itemsToGen.length <= 0 ? this.showList = false : null
        this.showList ? this.generateList() : null
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
    .dashboard-component__wrapper {
        width: 100vw;
    }
</style>

<template>
    <div class="dashboard-component__wrapper d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="dashboard-component__wrapper__shopping-items">
            <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.itemId" class="item">
                <ShoppingItem @renderEvent="getChangesFromRender" :itemProp="item" :item-index="index" :showList="this.showList" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <AddItemModal />
        <NewItemButton />
        <GenerateListButton @generateList="generateList" v-if="showGenerateListBtn" />
        <ListComponent v-if="showList" :itemsProp="itemsToGen" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Everytime I have a list generated, the message comes up on console:

> [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component
> . This means you have a reactive effect that is
> mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself.
> Possible sources include component template, render function, updated
> hook or watcher source function.

After some tests, I came to the conclusion that the problem is on the call of the 'generateList()' method inside the 'updated()' hook. But still, this is a main behavior for the app and I don't know how to fix the error.

Comment: every time you call generateList, you are dispatching an action to the store which looks like will end up changing your items list, and hence updated. To stop the loop you need to check in your generateList method if you are really mutating anything, e.g.  if the newly calculated  this.items.filter(item => item.isSelected) is different from  this.itemsToGen

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion. I solved it by removing generateList method from the updated() hook and added the lines: this.itemsToGen = this.items.filter(item => item.isSelected); this.$store.dispatch("setList", this.itemsToGen); To the function passed to renderEvent event.

Comment: Instead of using the mounted and updated hooks, you should use beforeMount, beforeUpdate. If you modify data that affects rendering inside the updated hook you are triggering another update. beforeUpdate is called before render so it will not create a recursive call.